# Juniper berries for brewing pale ales

Tags: beer, ingredients, flavor, ipa, pale

I love the aroma of Juniper and want to feature it in my next pale ale. I'm currently extract/kit brewing, and I had a few questions about how to go about this:

- I read some tips about adding to secondary [over at this question](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/adding-juniper-berries-to-secondary). Does it ever make sense to add Juniper at another time? Say during the wort boil?
- I'm going for a flavor roughly along the lines of Mammoth Mountain Brewing Co.'s "IPA 395". Does anyone know what kind of Juniper produces this flavor (there seem to be many species...)
- If I am starting with a pale ale recipe, should I omit hops at any point in favor of the juniper? Or do I just add both?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions similar to this have already been asked and answered: http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10496/adding-juniper-berries-to-secondary
http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/does-the-species-of-juniper-matter-to-sahti

Comment: @TobiasPatton, thanks. Indeed I linked to the first one in my own question prompt. As mentioned, it wasn't the full answer I was looking for. The second reference has some useful info, although I'd never heard of Sahti before!

Answer (score 4):

1. The earlier in the process you add it, the more flavor you'll lose.  The aroma will be boiled off or driven off by CO2 during fermentation.  Boiling might extract flavor, but I'm guessing.
2. no idea
3. Add both

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't sure if there were additional flavor profiles that Juniper could impart during the boil (as hops do). Perhaps I'll just have to experiment!

Comment: Agree on re:aroma, for the most part. I think steeping juniper in hot water (vs cool, warm) will extract more flavor, possibly aroma as well, because it's generally dry and it's a lot like a spice. I'm not sure if actively boiling it for a long time will help the flavor though. Short boil may be useful, certainly for sanitizing. Grinding it may help too.